# Can we call 'ever' as a specifier?

Tags: determiners

> He does **not** like planes.
>  She **never** eats meal. (English Syntax and
>   Argumentation, Bas Aarts)

Aarts calls the negatives, not and never, as specifiers. 
‘Ever’ in the example below seems to take the same position and role; can we call it as a specifier or not?

> “Good evening, madam; I sent to you for a charitable purpose.  I have
>   forbidden Adèle to talk to me about her presents, and she is bursting
>   with repletion; have the goodness to serve her as auditress and
>   interlocutrice; it will be one of the most benevolent acts you
>   **ever** performed.” (Jane Eyre)

Comment: I appears that "specifier" is a functional denomination and therefore depends on the semantic significance of a word/ phrase in the clause/ sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *ever* serves as a specifier (specifically, a qualifier) in that sentence.

As noted in a tcnj.edu [syntax webpage](http://gsteinbe.intrasun.tcnj.edu/tcnj/linguistics/syntax.htm), *always, perhaps, often, never,* and *almost* are some of the qualifiers in English.  Toward the end of that webpage, another list of qualifiers appears, this time including *not, sometimes,* and *ever*.  Some additional information from that webpage is given below.

Specifiers are shown as being of three kinds: Qualifiers, Determiners (like *a, the, this, that, these, their, its, those, my, his, her, your* and proper-noun
possessives), and  Degree Words (like *too, so, very, more, most, quite*).

Verb phrases (such as *ever performed*) are shown as consisting of a possible specifier that is a qualifier, followed by a verb, followed by a possible complement.  A verb phrase can also have zero or more modifiers (adverbs and adverb phrases).  That is, a verb phrase can have zero or one qualifiers and zero or more modifiers.

Comment: Thank you. ELU and ELL are the very place for improving my understanding English.